# ForkJoinPool::shutdown vs ForkJoinPool::shutdownNow after ForkJoinPool::join

Tags: java, multithreading, fork-join, forkjoinpool

Code:

```java
            final ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(PARALLELISM_NUMBER);
            try {
                final List<Record> records = getRecrods();
                List<List<Record>> partitionRecordLists = Lists.partition(records, BATCH_SIZE);

                forkJoinPool.submit(() ->
                        partitionRecordLists.parallelStream().forEach(this::performSomething)
                ).join();
                
            } finally {
                forkJoinPool.shutdown();
            }
```

I have above code to perform some tasks in parallel. Given that `join` already makes caller thread wait until completion, wondering if it should be `shutdowNow()` instead of `shutdown()` in the `finally` block.

Note:`performSomething` only reads from the input list.

Answer (score 1):

Generally: `shutdown();` implies you are doing clean / ordered shutdown for the executor service, and `shutdownNow();` used for particular circumstances - often for error handling or to bypass any not started and less-important background services.

In you case there would not be any difference as you use `join()`. However consider another person maintaining your code: the `join()` is less obvious to see inside the code block so they would find it strange to see `forkJoinPool.shutdownNow();` at the end without a comment explaining why that was OK there, and `shutdown()` is more obvious neater way to indicate that the end of pool processing has completed.

```
final ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(...);
try {
    // Long block:
    // harder to spot join() here whereas shutdown() stands out
} finally {
    forkJoinPool.shutdown();
}
```